# doxygenlayout- mainpage visible no does not work

Tags: layout, doxygen

I need a really simple documentation just of my properties of a class. I created a Layoutfile where I changed the properties visible="no" just not of the classindex. It works pretty fine just 2 problems:

1. The mainpage is still visible
2. It is preselected

Is it possible to make the classindex to the main page and how can I change the configuration that it is generated this way. Here the part of my layout file "navindex":

```
<navindex>    
<tab type="classindex" visible="$ALPHABETICAL_INDEX" title=""/> 
<tab type="mainpage" visible="no" title=""/>
<tab type="pages" visible="no" title="" intro=""/>
<tab type="modules" visible="no" title="" intro=""/>
<tab type="namespaces" visible="no" title="">
  <tab type="namespacelist" visible="no" title="" intro=""/>
  <tab type="namespacemembers" visible="no" title="" intro=""/>
</tab>  
<tab type="classes" visible="no" title="">      
  <tab type="classlist" visible="no" title="" intro=""/>      
  <tab type="hierarchy" visible="no" title="" intro=""/>
  <tab type="classmembers" visible="no" title="" intro=""/>
</tab>  
<tab type="files" visible="no" title="">
  <tab type="filelist" visible="no" title="" intro=""/>
  <tab type="globals" visible="no" title="" intro=""/>
</tab>
<tab type="examples" visible="no" title="" intro=""/>
```

Comment: Apparently not. I'm not sure if this is by-design or a bug. When you delete the `mainpage` tab tag altogether, it is just re-created automatically and stuck at the end. When you set its `visible` attribute to `no`, it is just ignored and shown anyway.